# How was Mao Anying killed?

Tags: mao-zedong, korean-war

Mao Anying, the eldest son of Mao Zedong, was killed in action by an air strike during the Korean War.

There is the abstract from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mao_Anying):

> Mao was Peng Dehuai's secretary and Russian translator in the Chinese People's Volunteer Army at the time of his death.[4] He was stationed in the army headquarters with Peng Dehuai in caves near an old gold mining settlement, which offered excellent protection from American air attacks. The evening of 24 November 1950, two P-61 Black Widows were spotted on a photo reconnaissance mission by the Chinese on the ground near the location.[5] The next day on 25 November at around noon, a South African Air Force A-26 bomber dropped four napalm bombs,[6] one of which hit a makeshift house near the cave, killing Mao Anying and another officer who were cooking their lunch in violation of war-time regulations of Chinese Army.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mao_Anying)[5][7]

However, the reference article 6 does neither mention about **South Africa Air Force** nor **A-26 bomber**, the article just say **UN army's B-26** killed Mao Anying.

**1.** Was Mao Anying killed by South African or by some other air force from other countries (within UN army)?

**2. Who commanded the air strike and who took part in the attack?**

Comment: @Mark C wallace do you see what i written

Comment: @Mark C. Wallace When you see the reference article (5) and (6) written in Chinese, both do not mention South Africa. I don't know why Wikipedia say South African air force dropped the bomb

Comment: Nancy Grace did it. [two weeks later Nancy Grace dies in mysterious "accident"]

Comment: The A-26 was called B-26 at the time, and the South Africans flew P-51. That is, he was probably killed by an American bomber if the B-26 story is to be believed. I have no idea how to answer who were the pilots though.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that was killed in a napalm strike by U.S. forces, although there is at least a slight possibility that the responsible aircrafts was South African.

> By then four US bombers had flown past the village where the headquaters was located. People thought the bombers went to bomb the Yalu River bridge. Mao Anying and the soldier went into the headquaters, and found some eggs Marshal Peng had saved for himself, and started cooking egg fried rice. At this time, an officer was checking on the headquaters staff, and noticed the smoke coming out of the chimney. He went inside and told Mao Anying to leave immediately. Mao Anying agreed to leave as soon as he finished the egg fried rice. As the officer was leaving the village, he saw the four bombers return from the north. They dropped napalm bombs on the village. Mao Anying's charred body was found afterwards in the burnt out ruins.
>   -  [Source](http://www.dailykos.com/story/2012/01/07/1052349/-Egg-fried-rice-the-real-Korean-War-legacy#)

---

> An American fighter-bomber swooped over the site, machine guns going, strafing from a low level, and leaving the Chinese no time to take cover. Casualties were not great, but one of the three officers killed was Mao Anying. Mao refused to have his son's body returned to China. Mao made no public expression about his son's death and Anying's death was kept secret for years. Peng Dehuai did not tell Mao Zedong of his son's death for weeks in fear of Mao's reaction.
>
> Another story tells that: The evening of 24 November 1950, two P-61 Black Widows were spotted on a photo reconnaissance mission by the Chinese on the ground near the location. The next day on 25 November at around noon, a South African Air Force A-26 bomber dropped four napalm bombs, one of which hit a makeshift house near the cave, killing Mao Anying and another officer who were cooking their lunch in violation of war-time regulations of Chinese Army.
>   _  [Source](http://www.paulnoll.com/Korea/War/General-Mao-Anying.html)

---

> On Thursday, the 60th anniversary of his death, a phalanx of North Korean officials paid their respects to Mao Anying, who was killed by an American airstrike while fighting as a volunteer in the Korean War and subsequently buried in Pyongyang. North Korean leader Kim Jong Il himself sent a wreath of flowers to the gravesite, according to reports by the state-controlled news agencies of both North Korea and China.
>   -  [Source](http://blogs.wsj.com/chinarealtime/2010/11/26/remembrance-as-reminder-maos-son-in-n-korea/)

Comment: The story of egg fried rice is fake. The guys next to mao said he was roaating apple